# SSH Keyless Entry multiple servers and users all non root

Tags: ssh

I have **ServerA** which serves a central backup server for all linux machines in the field. They sync with rsync. I need keyless entry for these machines - say **ServerX**, **ServerY** and **ServerZ**. The idea is to give each client server a separate username and home folder to backup to - thus isolating each server's data and risk.

**ServerA** has UserX, UserY, UserZ.

On **ServerX**:

```
[root@ServerX ~]ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@ServerA
[root@ServerX ~]ssh root@ServerA
[root@ServerA ~]
```

I can login as root without a password prompt

Now if I try using one of the other users on **ServerA**

```
[root@ServerX ~]ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub UserX@ServerA  
[root@ServerX ~]ssh UserX*@ServerA
UserX@ServerA's password: 
[UserX@ServerA ~]
```

The ssh-copy-id does not report any erros and appears to work- but yet I cannot log in to ServerA "key-less". I have tried a couple combinations of the commands, but I cannot get passwordless login as UserX into ServerA

I am sure I am missing something obviouse here. :) Any feedback or advice would be appreciate to get passwordless access for UserX,UserY and UserZ.

Thank you for your help and time,

Regards,

Rudolf

Comment: What is the problem that you're having?

Comment: I have updated the post to highlight the issue. How can I get UserX to log in to ServerA from ServerX without needing a password. It works for root, but not UserX